# How to Unit Test Spring Repositories

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

I have created a springboot project splitted into three maven modules, the domain layer, the core layer (contains persistence and business logic) and the web layer. I try to unit test my repository ProductRepository (located in the core layer)

```html
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // provide bridge between SpringBoot test features and JUnit, for usage of springboot tsting features
@DataJpaTest
class ProductRepositoryTest {
 @Autowired
 private TestEntityManager em;
 @Autowired
 private ProductRepository repository;
 

 @Test
 void shouldReturnProduct() {
  // given
  Product p = Product.builder().id(1).designation("Test").reference("TEST").unitPrice(150).build();
  this.em.persistAndFlush(p);
  // when
  Product found = repository.findByReference(p.getReference());
  // then
  assertThat(found.getReference()).isEqualTo(p.getReference());
 }

}
```

But the repository is always instanciated to null. I run this test as JUnit Test in eclipse and i got a nullpointerexception.

Here is my pom.xml file

```html
<dependencies>
  <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> 
   </dependency> -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency> 
 </dependencies>
```

Comment: Don't you need to provide some type of configuration to start Spring context?

Comment: Why would you test repositories? They are just interfaces that you are not implementing, spring implements them for you.

Comment: @Orion i follow this tutorial, i implement some custom method in the repository, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing. I will later test my business logic and my controller. But, for now, i'm struggled with this.

Comment: Annotations are correct. Do you have spring-boot-starter-test as dependency and a database in your pom.xml like a h2? Did you try to execute it via maven? What is the console output when spring tries to initialize the spring context and the db?

Comment: Yes i have spring-boot-starter-test and h2 as inmemory database. I comment the mysql dependency. Below is my pom file

Comment: @mszalbach i have this exception when i run the app. Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. Should i need to configure a datasource with h2 ?

Comment: Ok i change scope from test to runtime for h2 dependency and the application starts but my unit test failed

Comment: Since I can not see any pom.xml. Do you use a spring-boot-starter-parent for version compatibility of the dependencies?

Comment: @mszalbach i updated the post, you can see my pom file

Comment: I have a look in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test but i don't know what i am missed.

Answer (score 0):

You say you try to unit test the controller but you use @RunWith(SpringRunner.class), this is used for integration tests. This annotation starts the complete application. And you just want to test the repository. What you can do is create an abstract DAO which you can implement in your unit tests.

```
public abstract class AbstractRepository<RepositoryType> {
RepositoryType repository;
private DBI dbi;

protected abstract RepositoryType createRepository(final DBI dbi);

@Before
public final void setUpDataSource() throws Exception {
    final JdbcDataSource jdbcDataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
    // DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 ==> h2 will keep its content as long as the vm lives otherwise the content of the database
    // is lost at the moment the last connection is closed.
    jdbcDataSource
            .setURL("jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1L;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:path/to/file/init_test.sql';");

    final Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource(jdbcDataSource);
    flyway.setLocations("/path/to/locations");
    flyway.migrate();

    dbi = new DBI(jdbcDataSource);

    runDbScript("/data.sql");

    repository = createRepository(dbi);
}

private void runDbScript(final String scriptPath) throws Exception {
    try (InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(AbstractDaoTest.class.getResourceAsStream(scriptPath),
            Charsets.UTF_8); Handle h = dbi.open()) {
        RunScript.execute(h.getConnection(), reader);
    }
}
```

}

Now you can overwrite the createRepository method in your test class.

```
public class ProductRepositoryTest() { 

@Override
protected ProductRepository createRepository(Dbi dbi) { return new ProductRepository(dbi); }

@Test
public void testGetProductById() {

    Product response = repository.getProductById(1);
    assertThat(response).isEqualTo(someObject);
    }    
}
```

If you need a framework to mock objects you can use Mockito and if you need to mock static or void methods you can use PowerMock.

Hope this helps.

Comment: should i need to use all this boilerplate code just to unit test the repository ?

Comment: @podisto To test it this way you should. This is just one of many methods to test your repository. This is de convention we use in developing code and tests

Answer (score -1):

Add these annotations to your test classes.

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
public class YourTestClass {....
```

Answer (score -1):

here's a working version of your example - hope this helps. I think you may have some conflicting configuration or dependencies in your own project. https://github.com/tndavidson/springbootjparepositorytest

Comment: Thanks let me clone and check it, may be i have some conflicts as you said.

Comment: I can now run the unit test, but it launch the spring context

Comment: Ok i understand, so it seems that in order to unit test the repository layer, i should launch spring context because i use spring stuff aka the TestEntityManager.

Comment: As always, the link is expired. Please, always include the relevant code in the answer.

Comment: @tim davidson could you make public the repo